# Defining a function using an InterpolatedFunction from a data set

Tags: interpolation

suppose I have two data sets A and B, which are tables/lists/arrays/whatever Mathematica calls it, from an imported CSV. there'd be lines that look like this:

```
A = Import["file.csv"];
```

(the CSV file is two columns, x and y. the range of x in file A is not the same as in B, but they coincide at a given interval)

and then I get the interpolation function of A and B, let's call them Af and Bf. I add lines like these:

```
Af = Interpolation[A];
```

**above is edited**: wrong function (/edit)

But now I want a new function, C, defined as C = A+Bx. I write it like this:

```
C[x_] == Af[x] + Bf[x]*x
```

**edit**: I'm not really using A, B, and C, these are just placeholder names because the names I used are pretty long. I changed the stuff above to:

```
C[x_] := Af[x] + Bf[x]*x
```

and I get

```
"Tag Plus in (<<1>>)[x_] is Protected"
```

(/edit. tho plotting/evaluating it still gets me nothing)

I plot it and get nothing. I try to evaluate it and get

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0.1879, 1.937}}, <>] + 
   x InterpolatingFunction[{{0.1879, 1.937}}, <>])[0.2]
```

I looked online, and the only example I found used /., for an NDSolve problem, which didn't seem to work for my case. what am I doing wrong?

edit: it appears that restarting the program got rid of the "protected" error. the code works now.

Comment: `==` is for testing equality.  Use `c[x_] := Af[x] + Bf[x]*x`.  Note capital `C` is a reserved symbol, used by *Mathematica*.  -- Also, assuming the `==` is a typo (I don't see how you got anything), your output suggests you defined `C` by `Af + Bf*x` and omitted the `[x]`.

Comment: Should `Interpolate`  be `Interpolation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that does what I think you are trying to do.  It is best to avoid `C` as a variable name because it has predefined behaviour

```
A = {{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 8}, {5, 16}}
B = {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 0}}
Af = Interpolation[A]
Bf = Interpolation[B]
c[x_] := Af[x] + x Bf[x]
Plot[c[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```